# Fortran compile shared object which includes netcdf static library

Tags: makefile, fortran, shared, .so

I am trying to create a shared object in fortran, that uses the netcdf static library. 
The ultimate aim is to use this shared object in R, but I think the problem starts with my makefile, so I am just focusing on this here:

In my makefile i use the following flags

```
'F90 = ifort
FFLAGS = -O3 -fPIC -r8 # double-precision now run in Fortran , -fpic 
for creating shared object file
LDFLAGS = -lnetcdff -lnetcdf -shared   #-shared, for creating a shared    
object file'
```

I think I managed to link everything allright, (you see all my object files below in the error message), but in the next step, when creating the shared object, there is a netcdf-library specific error message:

```
'ifort -O3 -fPIC -r8  -o HX.so HX.o HANDLE_ERR.o GET_CLM.o INTEGRATE.o 
CLIMATE.o STATE.o PARAMETERS.o CONTROL.o HYDRO.o DYNAMICS.o CARBON.o 
RINGS.o INIT.o SET_PARAMS.o -lnetcdff -lnetcdf -shared
ld: /usr/local/Cluster-Apps/netcdf/4.1.3/lib/libnetcdff.a(netcdf4.o): 
relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a 
shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/Cluster-Apps/netcdf/4.1.3/lib/libnetcdff.a: could not read     
symbols: Bad value
make: *** [HX.so] Error 1'
```

I find 'similar' problems, but as I am not familiar with the terminology and this is my very first try in generating a shared object, I cannot follow their instructions for my problem.

Comment: Well, yes, the objects in netcdf would need also to be built with pic relocatability, if you don't use a compatible netcdf.,so

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the dynamic (.so) version of NetCDF, be it from your repository or by compiling it yourself. As tim18 say in the comments, it also needs to be compiled with -fPIC, and the .so version will be.